# How to evaluate stored functions?

Tags: sql, vbscript

I have the following saved in a database.

```
    Function SearchFileForName()
        SearchFileForName = False
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set csvFile = fso.OpenTextFile("ListOfUsers.csv", 1)
        Do Until csvFile.AtEndOfStream
            if app.userID = csvFile.ReadLine then
                SearchFileForName = true
            end if
        loop
    end Function        

    Function WriteNameToFile()
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set csvFile = fso.OpenTextFile("ListOfUsers.csv", 8)
        csvFile.WriteLine app.userID
    end function        

    Function theMessage()
        if weekday(Now()) = vbfriday then
            response = msgbox ("Great Job "& split(app.userid, ".")(0) & "!" & _
                     vbnewline & vbnewline & _
                     "Keep up the good work and keep that morale high." & _ 
                      vbnewline & vbnewline & _
                     "Would you like a cookie for your efforts?", vbyesno)

            if response = vbyes then
                msgbox "Enjoy =)" & _
                             vbnewline & _
                             vbnewline & _
                       vbnewline & _
        "             _ . : : : : : . _" & vbnewline & _
        "         . : : : ` _ | _ ` : : : ." & vbnewline & _
        "     /  : : `   - - | - -   ` : : \" & vbnewline & _
        "   | : `   . - - - ` - - - .  `  : |" & vbnewline & _
        "   | :  (   O   R   E   O   )  : |" & vbnewline & _
        "   | : :   ` - - - - - - - `   : : |" & vbnewline & _
        "     \   : : : . . .  . . . . : : :  /" & vbnewline & _
        "         ` : : : : : : : : : : : `" & vbnewline & _
         "               ` ` ` ` ` ` `" & vbnewline

            elseif response = vbno then
                msgbox "That is too bad." & vbnewline & _
                             "Here is a cookie anyways." & vbnewline & _
                       "Enjoy =)" & _
                             vbnewline & _
                             vbnewline & _
                       vbnewline & _
        "             _ . : : : : : . _" & vbnewline & _
        "         . : : : ` _ | _ ` : : : ." & vbnewline & _
        "     /  : : `   - - | - -   ` : : \" & vbnewline & _
        "   | : `   . - - - ` - - - .  `  : |" & vbnewline & _
        "   | :  (   O   R   E   O   )  : |" & vbnewline & _
        "   | : :   ` - - - - - - - `   : : |" & vbnewline & _
        "     \   : : : . . .  . . . . : : :  /" & vbnewline & _
        "         ` : : : : : : : : : : : `" & vbnewline & _
         "               ` ` ` ` ` ` `" & vbnewline
            end if
        end if
    End Function        

    Function easterEgg()
        if not SearchFileForName() then
            WriteNameToFile
            theMessage
        end if
    end Function
```

So I call it with the following sql query

```
    Function easterEgg0()
        Set rseasterEgg =  CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
            rseasterEgg.Open _
                "   SELECT  dyCode " & _
                "   FROM        DDCode " & _
                "   WHERE       dyName = 'EasterEggScript'", _
                 Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
            Execute rseasterEgg.fields("dyCode").value
            Call easterEgg
    End Function
```

When I print it out it looks exactly as expected. But when I try to run it I get an error saying Typemismatch: 'SearchFileForName'?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN - [Execute Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

> The context in which the **Execute** statement is invoked determines what
>   objects and variables are available to the code being run. In-scope
>   objects and variables are available to code running in an **Execute**
>   statement. However, it is important to understand that if you execute
>   code that creates a procedure, that procedure does not inherit the
>   scope of the procedure in which it occurred.
>
> Like any procedure, the new procedure's scope is global, and it
>   inherits everything in the global scope. Unlike any other procedure,
>   its context is not global scope, so it can only be executed in the
>   context of the procedure where the **Execute** statement occurred.
>   However, if the same **Execute** statement is invoked outside of a
>   procedure (i.e., in global scope), not only does it inherit everything
>   in global scope, but it can also be called from anywhere, since its
>   context is global.

To overcome this use [ExecuteGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) instead.

```vb
Function easterEgg0()
    Set rseasterEgg =  CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        rseasterEgg.Open _
            "   SELECT  dyCode " & _
            "   FROM        DDCode " & _
            "   WHERE       dyName = 'EasterEggScript'", _
             Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText
        ExecuteGlobal rseasterEgg.fields("dyCode").value
        Call easterEgg
End Function
```